# Is there a ManicTime alternative for Linux?

Tags: linux, time-management

## Background

I'm looking for an app that can automatically record my app usage throughout the day so I can check back to see later what I've been up to, when, and for how long.

I really like the GUI of ManicTime. There are 3 timelines: App usage, document within the app (mainly getting it from the window title I presume), and computer status: Using/Away/Off.

But unfortunately the creators of ManicTime [don't seem to be very interested in supporting Linux](http://forum.manictime.com/yaf_postst210findunread_I-miss-ManicTime.aspx).

## So far

I know about RescueTime, which comes the closest to what I am looking for. Its UI is not as detailed as I'd like. AFAIK there is no down-to-second timeline that I can explore. It is also concerning that all app usage is uploaded to the cloud. I'd prefer to keep that data local.

Click based (manual) time trackers I am not interested in. I'm quite certain I'd forgot to start and stop tracking. And even if I wouldn't it would definitely be much less detailed data than an automated solution.

Is there an app that is similar that I may not be aware of?

Is there a way to make ManicTime work with wine reliably?

## Making it

It shouldn't be too hard to make, actually. We just need 2 ingredients:

1. A way to get current window title/active application from the background transparently, without disturbing the user
2. GUI to render collected data

I thought (1.) may be a technical challenge, but apparently that is not so: 
https://superuser.com/questions/382616/detecting-currently-active-window

(2.) is much more straightforward once we have our database with usage data in it, but it can also be labor-intensive to make a UI that is similarly polished as ManicTime.

Who would be interested in an open source project to implement this together? :) Maybe even with Functional Reactive Programming library in Haskell? :)

## Misc

I'm mainly looking for (free and) open source software, but I'd like to know if such commercial and/or closed source software exists as well -- especially if no (F)OSS versions are available.

Comment: I use [KTimeTracker](https://www.kde.org/applications/utilities/ktimetracker/). It unfortunately doesn't track individual applications, but is able to associate specific projects with virtual desktops. e.g. Desktop 1 <> web browsing, Desktop 2 <> Programming, etc...

Answer (score 2):

You can use [WhatPulse](http://www.whatpulse.org/):

- Most features are free (but not the application activity graph)
- Windows/Mac/Linux
- Stats are [available online](http://www.whatpulse.org/Franck.Dernoncourt#apps) as well as on the desktop client (from which you can export them as CSV).
- Support several computers
- It records application activities (premium only)

[image]